# Question about database which includes date variable

Tags: r

Good day.

I'm working with R. I have a database with names as a character type and date_A what is a date variable.
The database shows people and the corresponding date they got a medicine. Some people appear only ones because they have only used the medicine ones, while other appear more often and hence have different days assigned to them.

I need to make another database with same field, but only showing each person and the first date (the oldest date) assigned to him.  I tried to do this, but I need a confirmation to know if the code I wrote gives this information correctly.  Here is the code:

```
person_ones <- database %>%
  select(person, date_A) %>% 
  group_by(person)%>%
  mutate(oldest_day = min(date_A))%>%
  select(Dulkodi, oldesst_day)%>%
  distinct()
```

Any help would be great.
Best regards,
Gunnar

Comment: Try `database %>% slice_min(date_A, by = person)`

Comment: That looks as if it should work, apart from the typos - `oldesst_day` and `Dulkodi` (which should presumably be `person`).

Answer (score 0):

Your query should work perfectly fine (if you fix the spelling in the last select), but it would make more sense to use `summarise` instead of `mutate` which ensures that you only get one row per `person`.

```
database |>
  group_by(person) |>
  summarise(
    first_date = min(date)
  )
```